# Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo problema al acceder a un dato en especifico de un arreglo

[image: arreglo]

intente

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    print_r($value->mat_id);

  }
```

y me sale Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando realizaste el **`print_r`** , el tipo de dato te da como resultado que es un [Array](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php), y al ser tipo array , obviamente no es un objeto por ello el error

> Trying to get property of non-object

Para recorrer el array utilizando foreach es de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    print_r($value["mat_id"]);

  }
```

Comment: gracias por la explicación, tienes toda la razón

Answer (score 0):

Lo estas recorriendo mal. Cuando haces el foreach $value asume los valores directamente por lo que no hay ningun objeto.

Prueba así

```
foreach ($data as $clave => $valor) {
    print_r($valor);
}
```

Comment: Pero necesito la clave para buscar el dato especifico  del arreglo

Comment: Tienes los pares de clave valor del Array en $clave => $valor en el `foreach`